# Getting data from outside of group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a lot of devices non-periodically inserting data into mongo.
I need to get statistics of this data (value by day/month/year). Currently i am doing this by adding a field where I parse the date to day month and year using `$month`, `$year`, `$dayOfMonth`. Then grouping them by these values. The problem is when I get no (or only one) data a day. Then I cant get actual value in this day because I need 2 values to subtract.
Is there a way to get the closest document by day to this group? in one query?

**Lets say I have data:**

```
{id : 1, ts : "2017-12-15T10:00:00.000Z", value : 10}
{id : 2, ts : "2017-12-15T17:00:00.000Z", value : 10}
{id : 2, ts : "2017-12-14T12:00:00.000Z", value : 6}
{id : 1, ts : "2017-12-14T15:00:00.000Z", value : 10}
{id : 1, ts : "2017-12-14T10:00:00.000Z", value : 10}
{id : 2, ts : "2017-12-14T09:00:00.000Z", value : 3}
```

**Explanation of problem:**

The value is actual read from the meter, for example lets say consumed energy. If device sonsumes 4W/min after 1 min it will be 4 after 2 minutes it will be 8. So the delta between 1. and 2. minute will be 4 . If i have record from `2017-12-14T23:58:00.000Z` lets say *10W*  *23:59* it will be *14W* so dValue should be 4 and *00:00* the next day i am not able to calculate the dValue because this is the first and only record in this group

If I group this data by day I can calculate the value difference only in `2017-12-14`.
For now I am using this **query**:

```
{
   $addFields : {
      month : {$month : "$ts"},
      year : {$year : "$ts"},
      day : {$dayOfMonth : "$ts"}
   }
},
{
   $group : {
      _id : {
         year : "$year",
         month : "$month",
         day : "$day",
         id : "$id"
      },
      first : {$min : "$$ROOT"},
      last : {$max : "$$ROOT"},
   }
},
{
   $addFields : {
      dValue: {$subtract : [last.value, first.value]} //delta value
   }
},
```

This query works but only if there is more than one document in a day. If there is only one document i cant get accurate data. I want to do this in one query, because i have a lot of these devices and the number is going to only increase and if i have to do a query for every device i get insane number of queries to the database. Is there a way how to solve this ?

Comment: What is the `dValue` field (can you explain the meaning of it)?

Comment: It means delta value (value change) of the day. I have meter which i read and post the data to the DB (value field). I need the change of the value in day.

Comment: So what delta value do you expect if there is only one record. If today the whole day you only get value: 5 and there is no other document for today what delta value do you expect? 5 or 0 or something else?

Comment: I expect to get the last value from yesterday minus the first value of today. Because if there is any usage before the first record it will say that delta is 0 for today which is not true. Another example. Device uses 10W before the first recort of today. I will get the value, but i would not know that the device used 10W because i dont have access to the last value of yesterday, because it is in the other group

Comment: I think you are hitting the limits of aggregation-framework. I believe map-reduce is a better fit for this usecase.